# How can I pass JQgrid data to controller using jqGrid data type local

Tags: jquery, grails, jqgrid

I use Jqgrid with datatype local. The problem I am facing is I can't send jqqrid data to Grails controller class.  How can I pass JQgrid data using data type:local to controller class.

Comment: Please post what you have done and any code that is not working.

Comment: Also have a look at [JQGrid plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jqgrid), if you have not used it already.

Comment: i agree to Alidad, just post your data to server!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `datatype` parameter to something else using the `setGridParam` method from an event of your choosing.  See the [docs here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods). Also, see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209620/trying-to-understand-jqgrid-for-jquery-how-do-i-change-the-url-for-my-ajax-call).